# Daylight Saving Issue

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, dst, datetimeoffset

I am using MySQL with EDT timezone. During time shift (2016 Sun, 3 Mar, 02:00). I can see this weird behavior where mysql ignore my 2ed condition(in bold below).Is there a way to fix this issue..?

```
mysql> explain select resId,resTimeStamp from RESUME 
        where resTimeStamp >='2016-03-13 1:58:00' && resTimeStamp < '2016-03-13 1:59:00'
```

**rows parsed = 9**

```
mysql> explain select resId,resTimeStamp from RESUME 
        where resTimeStamp >='2016-03-13 1:59:00' && resTimeStamp < '2016-03-13 02:00:00';
```

**rows parsed = 2436217**

mysql treat above query as explain select resId,resTimeStamp from RESUME 
            where resTimeStamp >='2016-03-13 1:59:00' only ignoring && **resTimeStamp < '2016-03-13 02:00:00';**
Is it possible to tweak mysql to consider 2016-03-13 02:00:00 to 2016-03-13 02:59:59 as 2016-03-13 03:00:00

Comment: The time `2016-03-13 02:00` doesn't exist, because the clock jumps immediately from `1:59:59` to `03:00:00`.

Comment: What happens if you change it to `2016-03-13 03:00:00`?

Comment: then it works fine. is it a bug or a feature ..?

Comment: Is there any way to make mysql treat  **2016-03-13 02:00:00 to 2016-03-13 02:59:59** as 2016-03-13 03:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is because of [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). When you "spring ahead" an hour goes missing.

Frankly, time zones are a nightmare best avoided where possible. In general it's a good idea to [set your database time zone to use UTC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) and to store all datetimes as [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). This avoids worrying about things like time zones or Daylight Savings Time. You can use [`CONVERT_TZ`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) to handle conversions, or your programming language's own time zone conversion functions.

Comment: Is it possible in mysql through any patch or setting to change 2016-03-13 02:00:00 to 2016-03-13 02:59:59 as 2016-03-13 03:00:00 for all years.
I believe then my issue will be solved.

Comment: @GauravSaini Sure, you could patch MySQL... theoretically. And then maintain that patch across MySQL versions. I think you're going around it the wrong way. Let's back up. Where are these invalid dates coming from? Why are you storing your dates in the local time zone?